# Regex - Matching closest to literal text

Tags: regex

How do I stop on the closest period from a literal text to get "last sentence here"? My current regex ends up getting " middle sentence. last sentence is here"

My regex

```
\.(.+?ntence is he.+?)\.
```

Sample text

```
first sentence. middle sentence. last sentence is here. or is it?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure not to allow any periods to slip through:

```
\.([^.]+?ntence is he[^.]+?)\.
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qH4xB7/1

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is that your RegEx is not as non-greedy as you think.

1. At first your RegEx find the first period of your phrase.
2. Then is matches everything that follows until the phrase "ntence is he".
3. At the end it matches everything that follows until the next period.

You should use a negated character-class instead of the period to solve this problem e.g.:

```
\.([^.]+?ntence is he[^.]+?)\.
```

Comment: @Anonymous:  Because any other answer would have been incorrect. ;)  But seriously, this happens a lot.  You take your time writing the best answer you can, and only after submitting it do you see someone else has posted virtually the same thing (sometimes it's several people).  To be fair, he did explain it better.

Comment: Thanks nemoinho for explaining the reason why it doesn't work :]

Answer (score 1):

To get the last sentence (defined by ending in a period but not containing a period), without it caring about the content of your sentence, try this:

```
/\s*([^.]+\.)[^.]*$/
```

Example here with detailed explanation: https://regex101.com/r/jA3mC1/1

This is "PCRE" (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions)--all "RegEx" is not the same. I'm assuming you meant PCRE, but, you should edit your tags and include [pcre] or whatever regex dialect you're using.